# wait until certain code is run

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a continuation from this post - [:visible selector issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946058/visible-selector-issue)

Anyway, I was wondering if there is a way to detect if a particular code segment is run until it is completed before running a new line of code.

For example,

```
if(filterVal == 'all') {  
    jQuery('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');  
} else {  
    jQuery('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {  
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {  
            jQuery(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');  
        } else {  
            jQuery(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');  
        }  
    });  
}
```

What I want to do is make sure that all the list-item elements are successfully fadeIn(display:block) and fadeOut(display:none) successfully before triggering the jPages function to create pagination.

Comment: Take a look at the callback parameter of the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 2):

There's a parameter in [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) that takes care of that.

```
$('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow', function()
{
    // Fade has finished, continue here.
    //
    //

});
```

Comment: What if there are 8 items with this fadeOut method and I only want to run the code at the end of it? Because I want to implement the jPages script to all the list items.

Comment: @XavianTracy I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want the items to fade out after each other and act as though they're 'queued' or do you mean you only want the callback to run once after all 8 have faded out rather than 8 separate times?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a callback function. Try:

```
jQuery(this).fadeOut('normal', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hidden'); 
})
```

**If you have to do it many times, use:**

```
jQuery('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {  
    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {  
        jQuery(this).addClass('hidden');  
    } else {  
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hidden');  
    }  
});  

$('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeOut('normal', function(){
    //Finished
});
$('ul#portfolio li:not("hidden")').fadeIn('slow', function(){
    //Finished
});
```

Comment: What is there are 8 items with this fadeOut method and I only want to run the code at the end of it? Because I want to implement the jPages script to all the list items.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found out how to do it using [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

My code looks something like this:

```
jQuery('ul#portfolio li').promise().done(function()
{
    jQuery('ul#portfolio li').each(function()
    {
        console.log(jQuery(this).attr('class') + '-' + jQuery(this).css('display'));

    });

});
```